# ContainerContentChanging event and data model changes

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using the ContentContainerChanging event raised by the GridView to render a grid of image in my UWP app. The app is syncing some data from the web and the data is rendered as they are stored locally to a SQLite database. I have a couple of TextBlocks for two properties in my Model that I bind to from my XAML. I then load the images progressively in the ContentContainerChanging callback. This works great for data that is readily available for rendering but is at direct odds with one way data binding.

My understanding of this event is it is called every time the item is rendered on the screen. In my case, the model with the text data is available ahead of time while the image is still being downloaded. So they see a placeholder. But then once the image has been downloaded, there is no way to force ContentContainerChanging to be called again. When the image is fully downloaded, how can I tell the GridView to re-render only the items in the ViewPort? As the user scrolls, images are going to get rendered, but what if the user never scrolls?

I could refresh the whole ObservableCollection but that is an odd experience for the user. I see the items being removed and all items being added again. Technically, there are no changes to the model itself, only the images. So it seems wasteful. Also the scroll position/context is lost.

Is there a way to somehow kick off ContentContainerChanging again and force the UI to render my images again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Faywang. Your suggestion to bind to the full path to the LocalCache image worked well for me. That coupled with x:Phase seems to work exactly like overriding the ContainerContentChanging event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the images in GridView after they are downloaded, you could try to add a path property in your model and bind it with the Source of Image. The model needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=winrt-18362) interface and subscribe to the PropertyChanged event. When the images are downloaded, you can modify your ObservableCollection and pass the path to each model. In this case, the UI will automatically update to display your image. For example:

.xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Lists,Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

.cs:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public string url { get; set; }
    public string Url
    {
        get { return url; }
        set
        {
            url = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> Lists = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();

//pass the path of image

MyViewModel v = Lists[0];
v.Url = "https://picsum.photos/48?image=883";
```

Comment: Faywang, Thanks for your response. I'm aware that we can bind it this way. But there are a few details I may be missed.

1. The images are cached onto local disk first. Local disk URLs cannot be data bound as part of the source property AFAIK. SetSourceAsync needs to be called in that case.
2. I don't want to bind an ImageSource from the ViewModel because SetSourceAsync will need to be called for the entire list even with many items not being visible in the UI, which slows things down.

Comment: What is the local disk you mentioned? The local folder or c drive? If it is local folder, you can directly use "ms-appdata:///local/..." to bind it with the Source instead of declaring the ImageSource. In addition, how do you want to render images in the ContainerContentChanging event? Also using SetSourceAsync method?  When many items are not visible in the UI, the ContainerContentChanging event will also load all items, the SetSourceAsync method will also need to be called for the entire list.

Comment: Faywang, I definitely explored that option but i could not use ms-appdata because I'm using the LocalCache folder and not the Local folder. This is just data sync'd from another service. It does not make sense to back this data up and restore it later. I tried ms-appdata:///localcache but that did nothing. ms-appdata:///local works if i put something inside the LocalState folder

Comment: Yes, currently the ms-appdata supports the Local folder, Temporary folder and Roaming folder. However, according to your description, you save the pictures in the LocalCache folder, in this case, you can directly pass the full path of image to MyViewModel.Url, it can use the full path to access the files in the LocalCache folder(e.g. v.Url = @"xxx\LocalCache\x.jpg";).